# Explain scientific error

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

[image]

The third step scientific error, however, the book and the professor says it is 100% correct 
Please, I want to interpret and explain clearly her and thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with it? Is the third step a transform $e^{\ln|1+x|} = |1+x|$? If so, it's correct, as $e^{\ln a} = a$, $\forall a > 0$.

Comment: You mean the third line should be $|y| = \dots$?  That is, $y$ could be negative, and thus not equal to $|1+x| e^{c_1}$.

Comment: I think that is it (and this bit of sloppiness is then silently corrected by introducing the $\pm$ at the end).

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand the issue very well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't this has an error in it. In that third line the exponential is split by its multiplication rule, then e^ln(1+x) is simplified to 1+x.

What do you think it should be?

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand the issue very well.